# Pivot Table Grand Total at the top

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

We have an Excel spreadsheet with the Grand Totals at the top using a Forumla, but this isn't on the actual Pivot Table it's just in the spreadsheet.

We have a client that wants the Grand Totals at the top of the Pivot Table and doesn't want us to use Formula. Does anyone know if this is possible (even using VBA or something, just so long as we don't look for a specific column or row name and compare with it (so no GETPIVOTDATA("Grand Total...)))?

Answer (score 3):

This slightly hacky solution might help:

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot13.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible. I'm doing just that. Here's how. Let's say I in my data source, I have 1 column that contains various work orders. In another column I have all my total dollars spent for each work order, and in my final column I have a number that identifies all of the various work orders as being part of one whole group, or falling under one heading. In my case, each of the work orders fall under one project number. This will place your total at the top and at the bottom. It will also allow you to turn on and off the bottom or the top by selecting a choice under Grand Total on / off for rows / columns.

Kevin L

Answer (score 0):

It generally works. but many people in my team make different pivot table layouts. So than this "fake" grand total column really does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having a similar challenge, you can accomplish this by adding rows at top of the pivot table and using GETPIVOTDATA to put the values in any cell you chose. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146062/sum-specific-values-in-the-grand-total-row-of-a-pivot-table/74169355#74169355) for details on how to use GETPIVOTDATA to get the Grand Total of a column in a Pivot Table. The best part is that is dynamic. There's no need to reference the Grand Total row specifically.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be happy to be proved wrong, but I don't think it's possible. I think you may have to do a little work on managing your client's expectations...